# python json dict iterate {key: value} are the same

Tags: python, json, dictionary

i have a json file I am reading in; looks similar to:

```
[
  {
    "Destination_IP": "8.8.4.4",
    "ID": 0,
    "Packet": 105277
  },
  {
    "Destination_IP": "9.9.4.4",
    "ID": 0,
    "Packet": 105278
  }
]
```

when i parse the json via:

```
for json_dict in data:
    for key,value in json_dict.iteritems():
        print("key: {0} | value: {0}".format(key, value))
```

I am getting:

```
key: Destination_IP | value: Destination_IP
```

I have tried using `.items()` and I have tried just iterating over the keys via `iterkeys()` and `keys()` to no avail.

I can call it direct via `json_dict['Destination_IP']` and the value returns.

```
for json_dict in data:
    if 'Destination_IP' in json_dict.keys():
        print json_dict['Destination_IP']
```

returns:

```
key: Destination_IP | value: 8.8.4.4
```

I'm on python 2.7, so any help in running down the value portion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's just an error in the way you print it.  You wrote `"key: {0} | value: {0}"` but  you meant `"key: {0} | value: {1}"`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Change your string formats **index**:

```
for json_dict in data:
    for key,value in json_dict.iteritems():
        print("key: {0} | value: {1}".format(key, value))
```

Or without using index:

```
for json_dict in data:
    for key,value in json_dict.iteritems():
        print("key: {} | value: {}".format(key, value))
```

Also you can using names instead of index:

```
for json_dict in data:
    for key,value in json_dict.iteritems():
        print("key: {key} | value: {value}".format(key=key, value=value))
```

**Update**: In python3.6 and later, f-string feature added that allow programmers to make formatted string easiest, a f-string work same as template engine that starting by `f` prefix and string body come after, and variables and other dynamic things must determine between `{}` signs, same as below:

```
print(f'key: A | value: {json_dict["A"]}')

>>> key: A | value: X
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to specify an index at all:

```
for key, value in json_dict.iteritems():
    print("key: {} | value: {}".format(key, value))
```

Comment: This only works for Python 2.7, in 2.6 you have to write the positional values - _"Changed in version 2.7: The positional argument specifiers can be omitted, so '{} {}' is equivalent to '{0} {1}'."_

Comment: Nobody should ever use Python 2.6 anyway in 2015.

Comment: @ozgur CentOS and RedHat systems still use 2.6 as the default system Python, and there is a great deal of legacy code that runs on 2.6.